# Is there any way to separate every four row in a different column in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to separate every four row into column.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzWtk.png)

Like in screenshot, first 5 row that I bold of A becomes column of C D E F & G
I want every 5 row of A becomes column of C D E F & G in new row

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Adil, you may want to post a new screenshot so you're not publishing real contact details for people to the big wide world.

Comment: The details are already available publicly. So, I don't think this will be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*5,0)
```

and copy both across and down.

[image]

Comment: Once I enter formula in C1 only A1 is coming

Comment: @AdilAsif  After the formula is entered in **C1**, copy that cell first from **D1** through **G1**.  Then copy the row from **C1** through **G1** downwards.